# How to call WooCommerce update cart function programatically

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am rendering WooCommerce Cart items in a custom html table wrapper by a form that points to a custom PHP file.

```html
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="/update-cart.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update cart">
</form>
```

When I click on update cart, I get redirected via POST to `update-cart.php` where I do some business related actions with the PHP `$_REQUEST`.

After doing those actions, I want to call to the WooCommerce original update action, but I am stucked.

This is what I have tried:

```php
// Non of this has worked for me

do_action('woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated'); // 1

WC()->cart->persistent_cart_update(); // 2

do_action('update_cart_action'); // 3
```

How should I call WooCommerce's update action?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to update in the cart? The update_cart form handler is [WC_Form_Handler::update_cart_action()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L596); you could read that and see how it does whatever you want to do.

Comment: I cannot instantiate WC_Form_Handler class, I am getting a 'class not found'.
How can I get a WooCommerce class instance?

Comment: I don't think you should be, unless you want to process updates from a posted form? And it's a static method anyway: I'd guess you'll have to require_once wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wp-form-handler.php if it really isn't found, and then you can call WC_Form_Handler::update_cart_action() statically.

Comment: Actually looking at class-woocommerce.php, WC_Form_Handler is loaded automatically for all frontend requests, so you shouldn't have to load it yourself. But if you really do have to, try `include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/class-wc-form-handler.php';`

Comment: You are right, the class is already loaded. If you answer the question I will mark it as the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default form handler is a static method which you can call with

```php
WC_Form_Handler::update_cart_action();
```